# Comparing memory mirroring vs ECC

Tags: memory, ram, bios

I know ECC RAM hardware is inexpensive (but the motherboard and the CPU are not..) but I heard about memory mirroring and I couldn't find/understand how that really works, is that supposed to be a firmware functionality (BIOS?) or a kernel (linux) patch? Is there any frank available comparison between memory mirroring vs ECC?

Answer (score 1):

Memory mirroring and ECC are generally used in tandem, I believe. And they're not directly comparable.

ECC adds a small amount of redundancy to each memory entry in order to detect and perhaps correct memory errors upon a read. It can correct some but not all errors, and it generally reports a detectable-uncorrectable error (DUE) signal for errors that it cannot fix.

Memory mirroring duplicates all memory contents at the channel level, effectively halving the system memory capacity. Its main advantage is to tolerate an error in one channel by failing over to the other one, *if and only if you can detect which of the two channels is in error*. (This sort of organization is sometimes called a "self-checking duplex".)

Thus, it makes most sense to combine memory mirroring with ECC in order to correct ECC DUEs---if you use memory mirroring alone (without ECC protection) you will not generally be able to determine which memory channel is in error, and so you cannot fail over to the safe one.

Both memory ECC and memory mirroring require hardware support, and they are only available for server CPUs as far as I know. So neither a firmware or kernel update will provide them on a consumer CPU.

EDIT:

See for instance this flow chart from a [Lenovo Whitepaper](https://lenovopress.com/lp0778.pdf). The memory ECC would is used to determine if there is a (detectable-uncorrectable) data error or not, and then the memory mirror is used to recover from a DUE in one of the two memory channels.

[image: Memory Mirroring Recovery Flowchart]

Comment: Your answer looks ok to me but I wonder what this question is doing at StackOverflow. I vote to close the question.